# Getting error while creating organisational unit in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am getting below error when I network up. I have not changed anything in the first network code.

> Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing channelconfig
>   failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting
>   up the MSP manager failed: admin 0 is invalid: The identity is not
>   valid under this MSP [Org1MSP]: could not validate identity's OUs:
>   none of the identity's organizational units [[0xc420418960]] are in
>   MSP Org1MSP orderer.example.com       | panic: Error creating
>   channelconfig bundle: initializing channelconfig failed: could not
>   create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP
>   manager failed: admin 0 is invalid: The identity is not valid under
>   this MSP [Org1MSP]: could not validate identity's OUs: none of the
>   identity's organizational units [[0xc420418960]] are in MSP Org1MSP

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question is that you use `--id.type  client` while registering admin with CA, and if it doesnt work just put the `config.yml` file in the msp of every organisation with the contenet similar to

```
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/org2-ca-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/org2-ca-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
```

i haven't tried `id.type admin` it might also work!